# How to loop all values in a dataframe as the start value in maxLik

Tags: r, loops, mle

I'm doing Maximum Likelihood Estimation using `maxLik`, which requires specifying starting values. Instead of specifying a single value, is there any way that allows me to use all the values from a matrix as the start value?

My current code of `maxLik` is:

```
f12 <- function(param){
  alpha <- param[1]
  rho <- param[2]
  lambda <- param[3]
  u <- 0.5*(p12$v_50_1)^alpha + 0.5*lambda*(p12$v_50_2)^alpha
  p <- 1/(1 + exp(-rho*u))
  f <- sum(p12$gamble*log(p) + (1-p12$gamble)*log(1-p))}

ml <- maxLik(f12, start = c(alpha = 1, rho=2, lambda = 1), method = "NM")
```

I create a dataframe with the upper and lower bounds of potential start values:

```
st <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0, 2, len = 100),rho = seq(0, 1, len = 100),lambda = seq(0,2, length(100))
```

There are 3 parameters in my function, and my goal is to loop all the values in the above dataframe `st` and select the best vector of start values after running the model from a variety of starting parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is *f12* ever being used? And do you want to pass *alpha* and *rho* into function? And what is *lambda*?

Comment: @Parfait thanks for pointing out. These are typo here. I want to pass these 3 parameters in my function, and make the estimation.

Comment: And where does *param* passed into *f12* derive from? Moreover, there are two places where alpha/rho/lambda is being called: within *f12* and within *maxLik*? Which set do you want to use data from *st*? Both?

Comment: I state the function (`f12`) that I wish to do maximum likelihood estimation, then use `maxLik` to help me calculate the estimators, hence `f12` is an argument in `maxLik`. I want to use start values in `maxLik` because it is the function eventually produce estimators, but rho/lambda/alpha are the same thing in these separate function. Did I answer your question accurately? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) to pass the *st* columns elementwise through your methods. Here, `Map` will return a list of [`maxLik`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maxLik/versions/1.3-4/topics/maxLik) objects, specifically inherited [*maxim*](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maxLik/versions/1.3-4/topics/maxNR) class objects containing a list of other components. The number of items in this list will be equal to rows of *st*.

Notice input parameters, *a*, *r*, and *l* being passed into *start* argument of `maxLik()` and no longer hard-coded integers. And *f12* is left untouched.

```
maxLik_run <- function(a, r, l) {
   tryCatch({
      f12 <- function(param){
        alpha <- param[1]
        rho <- param[2]
        lambda <- param[3]
        u <- 0.5*(p12$v_50_1)^alpha + 0.5*lambda*(p12$v_50_2)^alpha
        p <- 1/(1 + exp(-rho*u))
        f <- sum(p12$gamble*log(p) + (1-p12$gamble)*log(1-p))
      }

      return(maxLik(f12, start = c(alpha = a, rho = r, lambda = l), method = "NM"))
   }, error = function(e) return(NA))  
}

st <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0, 2, len = 100),
                  rho = seq(0, 1, len = 100),
                  lambda = seq(0, 2, length(100)))

maxLik_list <- Map(maxLik_run, st$alpha, st$rho, st$lambda)
```

---

And to answer the question --*best vector of start values after running the model from a variety of starting parameters*-- requires a particular definition of "best". Once you define this, you can use `Filter()` on your returned list of objects to select the one or more element that yields this "best".

Below is a demonstration to find the highest value across each maximum likelihood's *maximum*. Use *estimate* if needed. Do note, this returned list can have more than one if the highest value is shared by other list items:

```
highest_value <- max(sapply(maxLik_list, function(item) item$maximum))

maxLik_item_list <- Filter(function(i) i$maximum == highest_value, maxLik_list)
```

Comment: thanks! I understand that `map()` applying the function to each element in the `st` (correct me if I'm wrong). But how does `Map(maxLik_run, st$alpha, st$rho, st$lambda)` means `st$alpha` correspond to the `alpha` in the `start argument`, `st$rho` is  the `rho` in `maxLik` `rho`? Do we need to make a vector as ` Map(maxLik_run, c(st$alpha, st$rho, st$lambda))`? In addition, an error `Error in optim(par = c(1.55, 0.33, 0.77 : function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters` appears when it selects a vector of start value. How should I avoid that? Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned, the *st* columns are passed into as *a*, *r*, *l* iteratively as single values. Does this error occur on my posted answer or your changed suggestion? I am seeing I missed a closing parenethesis of `expand.grid()` which I justed edited.

Comment: I understand the `Map` now. The error occurs when I run your posted code  `maxLik_list<-Map(maxLik_run, st$alpha, st$rho, st$lambda)`. I think it is because a vector from `st` cannot be used as start values. So I need to remove it if it's failed vector.  Thanks!

Comment: See update wrapping the user-defined method in `tryCatch()` where failed vectors will return NA in list of objects. Use Filter() to filter these empty items out: `maxLik_list <- Filter(function(i) !is.na(i), maxLik_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your logLik function is that you are calculating alpha,lambda,rho whereas your data already has them.Those are the lines with u,p and f12(that is also your function name!). Also it is possible to calculate log likelihood for one row as your log likelihood function has single indices. So you run the code using apply like this

```
#create a function to find mle estimate for first row
maxlike <- function(a) {
f12 <- function(param){
alpha <- param[1]
rho <- param[2]
lambda <- param[3]
#u <- 0.5*(p12$v_50_1)^alpha + 0.5*lambda*(p12$v_50_2)^alpha
#p <- 1/(1 + exp(-rho*u))
#f12 <- sum(p12$gamble*log(p) + (1-p12$gamble)*log(1-p))
}
ml <- maxLik(f12, start = c(alpha = 1, rho=2, lambda = 1), method = "NM")
}
#then using apply with data = st, 2 means rows and your mle function
mle <- apply(st,2,maxlike)
mle
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edit `f12` to `f` in the function to reduce confusion. I'm trying to fit the data into a specific function `f12`, and `f` is the structure of the function I want it to fit. My data do not have `rho\alpha\lambda`, they are the parameters that I want to estimate in `f`. My goal is to select the best start values from `st` to fit my function `f`. So I don't think I can delete `u\p\f` here. Would you mind also to explain how `apply(st, 2, maxlike)` work as the start value selection, if `ml` has already specify start values in vector `c(alpha=1, rho=2, lambda=1)` please?

Comment: Using the method by Parfait would work for you. But the problem is that there is no data source for p12 which throws an error. And to answer your question, st$alpha becomes maxLik alpha because in the maxLik_run function a corresponds to alpha value. Provide more details on p12,u,p,f